# Outputpanel does not rerender

Tags: apex, visualforce, rerender

I know this is a widely posted question, but I do not manage to find a proposed solution that work for me.

```
<apex:form id="form2">
<apex:outputPanel id="my_list">
    <apex:outputPanel id="testBeforeTable">
        <apex:outputPanel id="test2">
            <apex:repeat var="group" value="{!myGroups}">
                {!group.links}
                <div>
                    <div style="line-height: 25px; display: flex;">
                        <div style="width: 140px; line-height: 130%; vertical-align: baseline;"> {!group.name + ' : '}</div>
                        <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!group.list!= null && group.list.size > 1}" layout="none">
                            <div style="line-height: 130%; vertical-align: baseline;">
                                <apex:selectList value="{!group.selectedFromList}" size="1" onchange="myFunction()" style="padding-left: 8px; padding-right: 20px; width: 100%; min-width: fit-content; max-width: fit-content;">
                                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!group.myList}"/>
                                </apex:selectList>
                            </div>
                        </apex:outputPanel>
                        <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!group.links.size > 0}">
                            <apex:outputPanel rendered="{! !(group.list!= null && group.list.size > 1)}" layout="none" >
                                <apex:repeat var="link" value="{!group.links}">
                                    (stuff with var link)
                                </apex:repeat>
                            </apex:outputPanel>
                        </apex:outputPanel>
                    </div>
                </div> 
            </apex:repeat>
        </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:outputPanel>
    <apex:actionFunction name="myFunction" action="{!myFunction}" rerender="my_list, testBeforeTable, test2"/>
</apex:outputPanel>
</apex:form>
```

The function "myFunction" is correctly working and updating the value used in the apex:repeat loop. By using System.debug() on it, I can assert the value are correctly updated. However, the VisualForcePage does not update.

Comment: `rerender="my_list"` should be sufficient. Have you tried that?

Comment: Yes I did, unfortunately, it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, the issue was with an SVG tag that had missing information. It was situated into "(stuff with var link)".